# How to determine when a non precision approach does or doesn't have a Final Approach Fix (FAF)?

Tags: non-precision-approach, south-africa

I am curious to know how to know for sure whether a non precision approach has/doesn't have a final approach fix by looking at its plate. From what I can see, a Break Cloud and/or NDB procedure might not have a FAF, but I am not 100% sure. 
Can anybody give me an example of a NPA with FAF and NPA without?

These are two examples of NPA plates from South Africa. 
[image: FAWB Break clod procedure RWY 29]

[image: FAAB VOR A RWY 01]

Comment: Although we have NDB IAPs in the USA, they are becoming more and more rare. I know of no Cloud Break approaches. As a matter of fact, I don’t know of any approaches that do not have FAFs. Are these common in other countries? Were there ever any Cloud Break approaches in the US in the past?

Comment: These are quite common in South Africa. There are some Approaches without FAF's here, but I'm finding it hard to determine which ones they are.

Comment: Cape Town is in my top five favorite destinations. Post more approaches like this or links to where they can be found when you find them. The closest I can find to these in the US is our Visual Climb Over the Airport.